# Why does git compress and and write all the project files when I only commit small changes?

Tags: git, github

So, I created a repository for my project and made an initial commit of a couple thousand objects totaling around 500mb.

Then I made some minor changes that amounted to:
    5 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 132 deletions(-)

I committed those changes to a new branch.

When I pushed those changes git did this

```
Counting objects: 2308, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2303/2303), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2308/2308), 492.30 MiB | 1005.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2308 (delta 1009), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

As you can see, it compressed and "wrote" (writing objects) all the project files, which again amounted to a long wait.

I thought that git would only upload the changes and take a second to do that.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure why this happened. Git's algorithm for determining which objects you have that the other Git doesn't, and therefore needs, is imperfect. Some of the recent changes by Microsoft are designed to improve this; perhaps a newer Git would do better. In general, your Git infers things from their "I already have that commit" hash IDs, without chasing tree data structures. If you showed all your raw commit and tree data, the question could be answered exactly (but I'm not sure I would bother...).

Comment: BTW the above assumes you're using a Git server that implements a "smart" transfer protocol. You don't show the URL or name the server. Most are smart these days, though.

Comment: @torek sounds like that's a first push... at least didn't specify there was a push after first commit.... therefore, the remote doesn't have any objects, everything will have to be transferred

Comment: @eftshift0 There was an initial commit before me trying to push to a branch. For some reason in keeps uploading all the files despite the fact that they haven't changed. Also, I don't know what Git server I'm using, I'm using the most standard and basic things, pushing to a repo at github.com/name/reponame

Comment: Hard to say if you did anything wrong without having the complete sequence of git commands you used.